# Django pagination returning <Page 1 of 1> instead of list

Tags: django

Inspired by the [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/), I want to retrieve pages of 20 logs at a time using this function:

```
        logs_list = (
            Log.objects.filter(modified_object_id=device_id)
            .order_by("-created_at")
            .values(
                "username",
                "action_type",
                "modified_model_name",
                "modified_object_name",
                "group_name",
                "role_name",
                "workspace_name",
                "created_at",
                "modification",
                "modified_object_id",
                "user_id",
            )
        )
        # Pagination
        paginator = Paginator(logs_list, 20)
        try:
            logs = paginator.get_page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, raise exception
            ValidationError("page_number_invalid")
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            return Response(data=[], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        print(logs)
        return Response(data=logs, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I know that the `device_id` (UUID) and `page`(int) variables are correct. The `logs_list` Queryset contains multiple, valid values, but the `logs` value shows up as `<Page 1 of 1>` when it is printed, and the output of this method is `{}`.

Why is the pagination not working correctly?

Comment: try to remove the parentheses '()'  around logs_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get_page` returns a Page object not list, with the given 1-based index. That's why it is printing `<Page 1 of 1>`

to print the list  - `print(list(logs))`

You can also iterate with for loop like -

```
for log in logs:
    print(log)
```

If you are getting empty result then check your filter, try to print logs_list.